# Superset connection to Snowflake using key pair

Tags: python-3.x, sqlalchemy, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, apache-superset

I'm trying to connect to Snowflake from Superset using a key pair using the following instructions:

```
https://superset.apache.org/docs/databases/snowflake/
```

Here are my python packages for building the Superset 1.5.2 docker image:

```
pyodbc == 4.0.34
pymysql == 1.0.2
psycopg2 == 2.9.4
pymssql == 2.2.5
typing-extensions == 3.10.0.2
sqlalchemy == 1.3.24
sqlalchemy_dremio == 1.2.1
sqlalchemy-sybase == 1.0.6
sqlalchemy-drill == 1.1.2
snowflake-sqlalchemy == 1.2.4
snowflake-connector-python==2.7.9
```

Here is my sqlalchemy connection string.  Since I am using key pair, I am assuming I leave out {password} in the connection string:

```
snowflake://{user}@{account}.{region}/{database}?role={role}&warehouse={warehouse}
```

I put in the "SECURE EXTRA" field this with proper encoding for the line breaks:

```
{
     "auth_method": "keypair",
     "auth_params": {
         "privatekey_body": "-----BEGIN ENCRYPTED PRIVATE KEY-----\n...\n...\n-----END ENCRYPTED PRIVATE KEY-----",
         "privatekey_pass":"Your Private Key Password"
     }
 }
```

When testing the connection, I get the following error:

```
ERROR: Invalid argument(s) 'auth_method','auth_params' sent to create_engine(), using configuration SnowflakeDialect/NullPool/Engine. Please check that the keyword arguments are appropriate for this combination of components.
```

Am I missing a package or dependency?

Answer (score 0):

Please use [ache/superset:2.1.0rc1](https://hub.docker.com/layers/apache/superset/2.1.0rc1/images/sha256-35ff5d8879641545cb23a4f7a16213a0bdf0b00111a7605e6c6862c3c33ae380?context=explore), this feature was merge to 2.1.0rc1 version.